# Xcode Storyboard - Items not appearing

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uistoryboard, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a`UIView` in a Detail Scene in my storyboard and the strangest thing happens. When I try to add a simple`UILabel` and then run my app, it does not appear. Soooo weird.

Here is a screenshot of my entire split view controller with the detail scene:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is my Segue code:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSString *strPOIndex = [self.tableData[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Vendor"];
        LHContactsDetail *controller = (LHContactsDetail *)[[segue destinationViewController] topViewController];
        [controller setDetailItem:strPOIndex];
        controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem;
        controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = YES;
    }

}
```

I am able to add items to the Master Scene Navigation Item. But the label I added to the Detail scene is not appearing when I run the app.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: What xcode version are you using? Can you see the label in the storyboard? DId you use Auto Layout and Size Classes?

Comment: Xcode 3.6 I can see the label in the storeyboard, but not in the scene when I view the app on my iPad. I did not use Auto Layout or Size Classes. I just simply put a UILabel in the scene.

Comment: What was the label's origin and size?

Comment: And, origin/position?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78143/discussion-between-christophr-and-user979331).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this kind of issue is easy to debug, and you should learn how to debug.

Just enable view debugging in xcode, and leverage lldb, just print out the UILabel object and check if it is in its superview, and if the superview is in the window, etc.

For example: if you know your label object is 0x12345678,

on lldb, enter

`po [0x12345678 superview];`

If you see it is nil, then the UILabel is not added into superview

If it has a valid UIView object, you might want to reapeat to see where's the problem.  View debugging is quite a powerful tool to use for view debugging.